# How to make Mac Application (use Automator) which convert image file of PDF to eps file with ImageMagick

Tags: macos, imagemagick, automator

I want to automate convert image file of PDF to eps file with ImageMagick.
And I would like to be able to do this with drag and drop.
So, I'd like to create an .app file using Automator.

I tried following things.

1. Start "Automator.app", and Choose "Application" type for the document.
2. Drag and drop "Run Shell Script" into workflow area.
3. Setting the Shell is "/bin/bash", and the pass input is "as arguments".
4. Write the scripts below.

   ```
    for f in "$@"     
    do
        fname="${f%.*}" 
        convert $f $fname.eps
    done
   ```

When drag and drop an image file into .app file, the following error code will be displayed.

> The action "Run Shell Script" encounted an error.

How to fix it?

--

macOS Sierra(10.12)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that your environment `PATH` includes the location of `convert`. I would also suggest moving the file extension to `fname` assignment, and quote the path names (in the event of unicode file names).

```sh
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
for f in "$@"     
do
   fname="${f%.*}.eps" 
   convert "$f" "$fname"
done
```

*Tips*

- In Terminal.app run `which convert` to find the correct path to your convert binary.
- During development, redirect `convert` stderr to a log file so you can evaluate the error.

  ```
  convert "%f" "$fname" 2> /tmp/my_app.log
  ```